# Migrating a whole website to WordPress

Tags: migration

I have a whole website with login, sign up and many other features developed into it. The site contains multiple pages and it's developed using html, css, JavaScript and all the script files and webpages are developed using php mainly on the local server. I am using Xampp for development purpose. I want to migrate the whole system developed, to WordPress along with the databases too. I know there's tons of tutorial videos on the internet, but i am finding it quite difficult to follow. Any help or lead or a demo most specifically would be of great help.
P.S: I need to create custom pages in wordpress and incorporate the already existing pages into it. I don't really want to create fresh pages, as it's known to me beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Good decision to move to Wordpress, you won't regret the decision.

The best way to get started is to find a good video tutorial and then to get started on your site. I recommend this [tutorial by wpsculptor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DyARzdLKjKw) because it covers just about everything you will need to get started.

You do not need to get into any development at this stage, nor do you need to understand the database structure or code. My advice is to stick to the basics (covered in the tutorial) until you have a good understanding of how to create a website using the build-in Wordpress functionality.

Comment: Clearly there are some users on Stack Exchange whose only purpose is to mark down new users and people who are trying to help. This, despite the appeals from Stack Exchange for users to be respectful. How does marking down encourage new users or people trying to help?

Comment: Good tutorial, thank you for referencing this.